# What values can appear in the "selected" attribute of the "option" tag?

Tags: html, html-select

I have some markup similar to the following:

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected">Apple</option>
  <option selected="">Orange</option>
</select>
```

In this case, "Orange" shows as the selected item.  I would have expected making the `selected` attribute blank would undo its effects.  Is there a way to write this without simply leaving the attribute out?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Different browser may treat this attribute differently. According to the MSDN documentation (for Internet Explorer):

> To select an item in HTML, it is not
>   necessary to set the value of the
>   SELECTED attribute to true. The mere
>   presence of the SELECTED attribute set
>   its value to true.

In firefox and Safari this does work:

```
<option selected='false' />
```

From what I can tell by looking at the official WC3 standard for HTML4, the supported case is only:

```
<option selected='selected' />
```

You will either need to selectively emit the attribute, or use javascript to control which item is initially selected.

Comment: -1; this claim is false: *"From what I can tell by looking at the official WC3 standard for HTML4, the supported case is only: `<option selected='selected' />`"* On the contrary, https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-selected declares `selected` to be a boolean attribute, and https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2 explains that it is the mere *appearance* of boolean attributes that implies a value of "true" or "false". `<OPTION selected>` is actually used as an example!

Comment: Doesn't work in modern browsers nowadays.

Answer (score 45):

**HTML5 spec**

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-option-element

> The selected content attribute is a boolean attribute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

**Conclusion**

The following are **valid, equivalent and true**:

```
<option selected />
<option selected="" />
<option selected="selected" />
<option selected="SeLeCtEd" />
```

The following are **invalid**:

```
<option selected="0" />
<option selected="1" />
<option selected="false" />
<option selected="true" />
```

The absence of the attribute is the only valid syntax for **false**:

```
<option />
```

**Recommendation**

If you care about writing valid XHTML, use `selected="selected"`, since `<option selected>` is invalid and other alternatives are less readable. Else, just use `<option selected>` as it is shorter.

Answer (score 7):

the only allowed value for selected attribute in XHTML is "**selected**" so if you want your markup to be XHTML compliant and work across all browsers leaving it out is the only choice to make it unselected

Answer (score 5):

In HTML (as opposed to XHTML) a simple `selected` attribute, with no value at all, works fine:

```
<option selected>Apple</option>
<option>Orange</option>
```

In XHTML (including XHTML5) you need a value, which should also be `selected`:

```
<option selected="selected">Apple</option>
<option>Orange</option>
```

This also works fine in HTML.

This is generally the case for boolean values in (X)HTML. The way to set them to false is to omit them altogether. Setting values of `true` and `false` may work, but is nonstandard.

Note that for a list of options, the first is selected by default, so this isn't necessary at all in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, the existence of the selected attribute tells the browser that it is the selected item.  Anything inside the quotes is ignored.

Edit: What you could do (with Javascript) is look for option tags with selected="", and remove the selected attribute from them.

Answer (score 1):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_selected.asp), you should be setting it as: selected="selected".  This tells you which option is initially selected, and allows you to set it through script later.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any other valid values other than "selected" for that attribute. (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_selected.asp)

Answer (score -2):

You are better off setting the selectElement.selectedIndex property from Javascript, or removing the attribute altogether.

Comment: Down vote reason: Don't see why you'd ever be better off doing something in JS that there is support for in markup.

Comment: @WaldenLeverich First, this is a really old question: HTML5 and "modern" browsers didn't exist, so the layer of compatibility was JS. Second, I mentioned removing the attribute: the only consistent way to disable selection.

Comment: @Jeff: “this is a really old question: HTML5 and "modern" browsers didn't exist” — [the HTML5 spec certainly did](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/), and [work on it had been ongoing for some years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#History).

Comment: It was wrong a year ago, and it’s still wrong today! We can’t just let people be wrong on the internet.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Please identify what is wrong about either my answer, or my comment from Oct 2016?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite actually, please don't spend any more time on this.  Our time is better spent correcting actual problems in the real world.