# Make a checkbox checked or unchecked based on the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can we make a checkbox checked or unchecked programatically based on the value? That is to say, for a particular user if the value is true, the checkbox should be checked, else if the value is false the checkbox needs to be unchecked. I declared the checkbox in the following way:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
if(condition = true)
{
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Test, new { @checked = "checked" })
}
else
{
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Test)
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: im trying the 2nd line of code, with this , will the checkbox be checked or unchecked,if the value of text is true?

Comment: mark as answer, if it helped you. Also doin that will  improve ur accpetance rate.

Comment: This is incorrect: `checked="@(required ? "checked" : "")"` - if you want the element to be unchecked - the attribute should not be present at all.

Comment: Indeed @Alexander the example is wrong and costs me 5 minutes of my life that I want back :)

Comment: @Alexander noticed your comment after 4 years. Updated the answer +1.

Answer (score 33):

If you do not want to use @Html.CheckBoxFor for whatever reason and you'd like to stick to

```
         <input type="checkbox">
```

then this is what I found to be the best way to do it:

```
 <input @(Convert.ToBoolean(Model.YourPropertyHere) == true ?   "checked='checked'" : string.Empty)  type="checkbox" />
```

The code that @Yasser provided above:

```
    checked="@(required ? "checked" : "")"
```

Did not work for me because it was still adding the checked attribute to the element, and setting checked="" will still render the check box as checked, which was not the desired output, instead if you wrap the whole statement into a razor block like so:

```
     @(Convert.ToBoolean(Model.YourPropertyHere) == true ?   "checked='checked'" : string.Empty)
```

you will get the desired results.

Answer (score 19):

There is a simpler way to include or not include the `checked` attribute if you are writing our your own `<input>` instead of using alternatives such as `Html.CheckBoxFor`:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@isChecked">
```

Razor is smart enough to automatically generate either

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

depending on whether `isChecked` is `true` or `false`. No need for if statements or duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MVC and passing in model values correctly from your controller, then

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.checkBox1)
```

...is all you need. The html-helper does the logic to figure out whether or not to insert the `checked="checkbox"` code.

Otherwise, without the HTML-helper you can dynamically generate the attribute yourself (others have pointed out how), but don't make the mistake of thinking that `checked = ""` will leave the box unchecked. See  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228677/613004) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check/uncheck check box value in code-behind, you have to include an ID and runat server attributes in your check box tag.

```
<checkbox Id="chk" runat="server" class="chkbox"/>
```

code-behind:

```
if(yourcondition==true)
  chk.checked = true;
else
  chk.checked = false;
```

If you want to do it in javascript

```
<checkbox Id="chk" class="chkbox"/>
```

JS:

```
if(yourcondition==true)
  chk.checked = true;
else
  chk.checked = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(condition = true)
{
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Test, new { @checked = true })
}
else
{
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Test)
}
```

Comment: This appears to be practically the same (but with less detail) as in [the accepted answer from six years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11839591/1364007). [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21785828).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="filter_favorites" value="Favorites" @(loggedIn ? "checked" : "") />
```

So this is a simple radio button which checks *loggedIn* variable & if true radio button will be checked else not.

Answer (score -1):

You have to have a name for the checkbox,
eg:

```
<input name=checkBox1 type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

For functionality :

```
    if(x==1){
   checkBox1.Checked = true; //To Check
}
else{
   checkBox1.Checked = false // To Uncheck
}
```

Comment: where do i need to write that functionality, in my view page?