# why checkboxes are check while html value = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

When I go to edit page all my checkboxes are checked, while when I look in the html I have some of then set to false :

```
<input checked="false" class="hidden" id="cover_inspiration_image_ids" name="cover[inspiration_image_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="68">
```

I can't understand why the `checked` value are not working.
I also tried with `checked="checked"`

I tried with jquery : `$(".hidden").prop('checked')` and it return true

This is my code :

**covers/_form**

```
 - @inspiration_images.each do |img|
   - next if img.image.path.nil?
     .w-col.w-col-2.w-col-small-4.w-col-tiny-6
       label
         INPUT[type="checkbox" name="cover[inspiration_image_ids][]" id='cover_inspiration_image_ids' value="#{img.id}" class="hidden" checked="#{check_status(img, @cover)}"]
          .image-cov-pick
            = cl_image_tag(img.image.path, height: 190, class: 'img-to-pick').html_safe
           .white
```

**cover_helper**

```
module CoversHelper
  def check_status(image, cover)
    cover.inspiration_image_ids && cover.inspiration_image_ids.include?(image.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try passing the value as `Boolean` instead of `String`

```
checked="#{check_status(img, @cover)}"
#to
checked=check_status(img, @cover)
```

full code

```
INPUT[type="checkbox" name="cover[inspiration_image_ids][]" id='cover_inspiration_image_ids' value="#{img.id}" class="hidden" checked=check_status(img, @cover)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want checkbox to be checked, don't render its `checked` attribute at all, with any value.

Related: [What values for checked and selected are false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228658/what-values-for-checked-and-selected-are-false)