# Converting Boolean value from DB to Bootstrap switch input - Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-5

I have a boolean field in the database - `emails_allowed`. This is reflected in the user profile page as a bootstrap 5 switch input

To represent the current value in the database I am using the template language in the following manner -

```
<input class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: -1.5em;" type="checkbox"
                                    id="email-allowed" 
                                    {{ profile.email_allowed|yesno:"checked,unchecked" }}>
```

I was expected the template language to merely output `checked` or `unchecked` as a string. Instead it is creating a HTML attribute called `checked` or `unchecked` as shown below -

```
<input class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: -1.5em;" type="checkbox" id="email-allowed" checked="">
```

As a result, I am unable to change the state of the switch as it is permanently either `checked` or `unchecked`. Has anyone come across this issue? Any suggestions on how to solve this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no "unchecked" attribute, I would write it as: `<input type="checkbox" ... {% if profile.email_allowed %}checked{% endif %}>`  (Does it really render `...checked=""`? Have you checked the html source (Ctrl-U)? Might it be that you see this in the browser html inspector?)

Comment: Yes - there is no unchecked attribute but the template language requires a second value that corresponds to "no". Yes, it really does render as checked="" - I noticed it using view page source as well as browser inspector (Firefox)

Comment: Actually even the if-block is rendering checked="" I wonder if it is a browser issue. Am going to try a different browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of checkboxes in HTML5 is determined by the existence, or non existence of the checked attribute. You could set it to anything. [What values for checked are false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228658/what-values-for-checked-and-selected-are-false) and [HTML5 specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-checked)

Meaning behind the scenes you will always get a HTML attribute.
The onClick event will toggle this checked attribute for checkboxes.

The keyword `unchecked` doesn't do anything. You could change your template to:

```
<input class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: -1.5em;" type="checkbox"
                                id="email-allowed" 
                                {{ profile.email_allowed|yesno:"checked=checked"," }}>
```

---

If you want the word "checked" or "unchecked" as a string inside your input element like this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: -1.5em;" type="checkbox" id="email-allowed" "checked">
```

You'll need to change the template to also add the quotaion marks. You'll have to escape them:

```
    <input class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: -1.5em;" type="checkbox"
                                id="email-allowed" 
                                {{ profile.email_allowed|yesno:"\"checked\",\"unchecked\"" }}>
```

However i do not reccomend this. Because this is not a valid HTML attribute and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin Achenrainer pointed out in his answer, the problem is due to the fact that in HTML5 the mere presence of the `checked` attribute, regardless of its assigned value, causes the checkbox to be always noted as checked when posting data to the server.

So if you have a form like below preloaded with server data, where the checkbox is checked

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="email_allowed" class="form-check-input" checked>
</form>
```

when loading the screen, the checkbox will appear checked, as it should. But lets assume the user unchecks the box on screen and saves the form. The `POST` data will still note the checkbox as being checked. The only way around this is to use Javascript / JQuery and get the true state of checkbox.

```
$("#email_allowed")[0].checked
```

This value is either true or false depending on the state of the checkbox and if you send this value in the `POST` data the checked attribute will not impact your processing