# Angularjs set focus

Tags: angularjs, dom

I am using angularjs to add dynamic column and its working fine. But the problem is that when I am adding it from function want to set focus to dynamically added element, but if I try after adding function the dom said that element is not yet created. For detail please have look at my code.

```
$scope.addCol = function(){

    //to add column dynamically assign one object to column
    $scope.column.push({
        spName: "",
        spId: 0,
        claimedId: 0
    });

    var id = $scope.column.length - 1;

    if($('#sptext'+id).length == 0){

        alert("Element was not found");
    }else{

        alert("Element was found");
        $('#sptext'+id).focus();
    }

},
```

Here after adding column the flow goes inside Element was not found.

HTML Code:

```
<table class="table-striped" id="mainTable" name="mainTable">
    <thead style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;">
        <tr ng-if="$index == 0 && counter > 2" ng-repeat="rowContent in rows"  id="{{$index}}">
            <td name="{{rowContent}}1">
                <span >Heading / Question</span>
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="colContent in column" id="sp{{$index}}{{$parent.$index}}">
                //this span(element) I am trying to set focus while creating dynamically
                <span contenteditable id="sptext{{$index}}" >{{colContent.spName}}</span>
                <p style="display: none;">{{colContent.spId}}</p>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
</table>    

I am trying to set focus to `<span>` element but its not working.
```

Please give me any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350572/auto-focus-in-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/21351131#21351131

Comment: thanks for your comment its working for input parameter but not for span tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Ganesh** mentioned you have to add **tabindex** to span elements to allow them to be focused.
Additionally I advice you to use **directive** to handle this task. This is more Angular way than finding those elements in jQuery style.

Here you have [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WQ0vMjIfVxkewn4JvRCA?p=preview) with example how to approach this task:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var item = 'item ';

  $scope.list = [item];

  var i = 0;
  $scope.addToList = function(){
    $scope.list.push(item + i);
    i++;  
  }
});

app.directive('focusItem', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.focusItem, function() {
            element[0].focus();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think, for span to get focus by javascript, span should have tabindex set.

```
 <span contenteditable id="sptext{{$index}}" tabindex="{{$tabindex}}" >{{colContent.spName}}</span>
```

after this, following should work.

```
 $('#sptext'+id).focus();
```

Hope it helps.