# What is the correct value for the disabled attribute?

Tags: html, textbox, textarea

What is the correct value for the `disabled` attribute for a textbox or textarea?

I've seen the following used before:

```
<input type="text" disabled />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" disabled="true" />
```

Comment: The link I posted as a comment to js1568's answer confirms/clarifies what @Marc B is saying: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/what-values-can-appear-in-the-selected-attribute-of-the-option-tag/24588336#24588336 because both are boolean attributes (not flagged)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

- For XHTML, `<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />` is the valid markup.
- For HTML5, `<input type="text" disabled />` is valid and used by W3C on their samples.
- In fact, both ways works on all major browsers.

Comment: In html5, input is a void element and doesn't need a self closing slash: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag

Comment: @Daniel K. It doesn't need it, unless doing polyglot HTML/XML markup.

Answer (score 121):

**HTML5 spec**:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute :

> The checked content attribute is a boolean attribute

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

**Conclusion**:

The following are **valid, equivalent and true**:

```
<input type="text" disabled />
<input type="text" disabled="" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" disabled="DiSaBlEd" />
```

The following are **invalid**:

```
<input type="text" disabled="0" />
<input type="text" disabled="1" />
<input type="text" disabled="false" />
<input type="text" disabled="true" />
```

The absence of the attribute is the only valid syntax for **false**:

```
<input type="text" />
```

**Recommendation**

If you care about writing valid XHTML, use `disabled="disabled"`, since `<input disabled>` is invalid and other alternatives are less readable. Else, just use `<input disabled>` as it is shorter.

Comment: Note: If you use AngularJS, and need to bind disabled state to a variable, you can use [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) instead. Similar with other attributes like this, generally they have intelligent `ng-*` counterpart

Comment: `disabled={true}` works in reactJs JSX code but I'm sure it would get transpiled to one of valid/allowed HTML5 formats only.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried all of these, and for IE11, the only thing that seems to work is disabled="true". Values of disabled or no value given didnt work. As a matter of fact, the jsp got an error that equal is required for all fields, so I had to specify disabled="true" for this to work.

Comment: OP's question was about HTML (i.e. client-side controls). You are looking at server-side controls; those have different conventions. You'll notice the difference if you inspect the HTML output by your JSP. If you still have doubts, try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Levx5p3b/) in IE11.

Comment: I've seen the same thing on client side on IE 11 . IE 11 forces something to exist, so just setting disabled results in disabled=""

Answer (score 1):

## setAttribute() on MDN:

> To set the value of a Boolean attribute, such as **disabled**, you can specify any value. An empty string or the name of the attribute are recommended values. All that matters is that if the attribute is present at all, *regardless of its actual value*, its value is considered to be **true**. The absence of the attribute means its value is **false**. By setting the value of the **disabled** attribute to the empty string (**""**), we are setting **disabled** to **true**, which results in the button being disabled.

[Link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#javascript)

### Solution

- I think in **XHTML Strict** is right **disabled="disabled"**,
- in **HTML5** is just **disabled**, like <input
  name="myinput" disabled>.
- In **javascript** I am setting the value to
  **true** using e.disabled = true;
  or to **""** using setAttribute( "disabled", "" );

### Test in Chrome

```
var f = document.querySelectorAll( "label.disabled input" );
for( var i = 0; i < f.length; i++ )
{
    // Reference
    var e = f[ i ];

    // Actions
    e.setAttribute( "disabled", false|null|undefined|""|0|"disabled" );
    /*
        <input disabled="false"|"null"|"undefined"|empty|"0"|"disabled">
        e.getAttribute( "disabled" ) === "false"|"null"|"undefined"|""|"0"|"disabled"
        e.disabled === true
    */
    
    e.removeAttribute( "disabled" );
    /*
        <input>
        e.getAttribute( "disabled" ) === null
        e.disabled === false
    */

    e.disabled = false|null|undefined|""|0;
    /*
        <input>
        e.getAttribute( "disabled" ) === null|null|null|null|null
        e.disabled === false
    */

    e.disabled = true|" "|"disabled"|1;
    /*
        <input disabled>
        e.getAttribute( "disabled" ) === ""|""|""|""
        e.disabled === true
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, there is no correct value, all the major browsers do not really care what the attribute is, they are just checking if the attribute exists so the element is disabled.