# enable or disable checkbox in html

Tags: html, jsp

I want to enable or disable checkbox in table's row on basis of condition.

code -

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="repriseCheckBox" disabled={checkStat == 1 ? true : false}/></td>
```

if checkStat = 1, need to disable checkbox else keep it enable.

It's not working. It disabling all the checkboxes.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: what kind of variable is checkStat? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Pekka - checkStat is jsp variable, declared in same jsp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct value for disabled attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 73):

If you specify the `disabled` attribute then the value you give it *must* be `disabled`. (In HTML 5 you may leave off everything except the attribute value. In HTML 4 you may leave off everything except the attribute name.)

If you do not want the control to be disabled then do not specify the attribute at all.

Disabled:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
```

Enabled:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

Invalid (but usually error recovered to be treated as disabled):

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="1">
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true">
<input type="checkbox" disabled="false">
```

So, without knowing your template language, I guess you are looking for:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="repriseCheckBox" {checkStat == 1 ? disabled : }/></td>
```

Comment: good answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The HTML parser simply doesn't interpret the inlined javascript like this.

You may do this :

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="repriseCheckBox" name="repriseCheckBox"/></td>

<script>document.getElementById("repriseCheckBox").disabled=checkStat == 1 ? true : false;</script>
```

Comment: There is no `getElementByName` method. It is a plural method and returns a node list, not an element.

Comment: @dystroy - Thanks for you answer. But, checkbox will repeats in all rows with same id so its disabling all the checkboxs.

Comment: Never give the same id or name to more than one element ! You may use a counter to build dynamic names/id (`String id="repriseCheckBox_"+i++`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="t.IsPullPoint" onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"><span class="cr"></span></label>
```

Comment: Maybe let the OP know why you gave the answer you did, i.e. what is improved or why your code will work.  Giving a brief explanation means the OP can fully understand and help the next person, or the SO community.

Comment: now i find out one  bester one solution  ...   <td style=" **pointer-events: none;**" > <label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="t.IsPullPoint" **onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"** ><span class="cr"></span></label> </td>

Answer (score 0):

In jsp you can do it like this:

```
<%
boolean checkboxDisabled = true; //do your logic here
String checkboxState = checkboxDisabled ? "disabled" : "";
%>
<input type="checkbox" <%=checkboxState%>>
```

Answer (score -1):

According the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_disabled.asp) you might use JavaScript for disabled checkbox.

```
<!-- Checkbox who determine if the other checkbox must be disabled -->
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxDetermine">
<!-- The other checkbox conditionned by the first checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxConditioned">
<!-- JS Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get your checkbox who determine the condition
    var determine = document.getElementById("checkboxDetermine");
    // Make a function who disabled or enabled your conditioned checkbox
    var disableCheckboxConditioned = function () {
        if(determine.checked) {
            document.getElementById("checkboxConditioned").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("checkboxConditioned").disabled = false;
        }
    }
    // On click active your function
    determine.onclick = disableCheckboxConditioned;
    disableCheckboxConditioned();
</script>
```

You can see the demo working here : http://jsfiddle.net/antoinesubit/vptk0nh6/

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is a little old but here is my solution.

```
 // HTML
 // <input type="checkbox" onClick="setcb1()"/>
 // <input type="checkbox" onClick="setcb2()"/>

 // cb1 = checkbox 1
 // cb2 = checkbox 2
  var cb1 = getId('cb1'), 
      cb2 = getId('cb2');

  function getId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  function setcb1() {
    if(cb1.checked === true) {
      cb2.checked = false;
      cb2.disabled = "disabled"; // You have to disable the unselected checkbox
    } else if(cb1.checked === false) {
      cb2.disabled = ""; // Then enable it if there isn't one selected.  
    }
  }

  function setcb2() {
    if(cb2.checked === true) {
      cb1.checked = false;
      cb1.disabled = "disabled"
    } else if(cb2.checked === false) {
      cb1.disabled = ""
  }
```

Hope this helps!