# Populate default value in dropdown on JSP page

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have the following code in my JSP that uses Struts2 
Now my requirement is to have the **headerValue as Pending always** in the dropdown box and it should be **non-editable**

```
   <td>
        <s:select headerValue="Select" headerKey="" list="#{'Cleared':'Cleared','Exception':'Exception','Pending':'Pending'}" cssClass="select50" id="titleStatus%{#product.productId}">
        <s:param name="name">newContractTitles[<%=counter%>].titleStatus</s:param>
        <s:param name="value"><s:property value="titleStatus"/></s:param>
        </s:select>
   </td>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: then change your `headerValue="Pending always"` ? is that you want if not your question is not clear

Comment: @looser 
but I already have 'Pending':'Pending' in the list and can I remove and put it in headerValue ?

Comment: @Barewithme  it is `disabled="disabled"` actually. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to use value attribute of s:select, by setting value ='pending' in select tag.

Comment: @Amit Sharad,If I understand your question correctly ,you want default value of "Pending" to be shown in the drop down without making it appear twice.You can use "value" attribute to set the default value and exclude "headervalue" attribute.Let me know if this understanding is incorrect

Comment: Thanks yes that whats I want also Im writing a function editEnable() which again enables the dropdown so this is what I need

Comment: If you want your select element to be disabled intially and be populated with default value of pending,you can use <s:select disabled="disabled" value="pending" ..... /> . Later when you want it to be enabled on some event the JS function can be written as you mentioned ,which would have soemthing like document.formname.elementname.disabled = true; OR document.getelementByid(elementid).disabled = true OR by using jquery like  $('#elementid).removeAttr('disabled');Hope this helps.