# Enable/disable field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields in my form. One is populated from the site and one is user input. When the field is populated from the site, the field will be disabled, and when the user inputs it should be enabled. I am trying to pass a parameter that changes the value in either case. This doesn't seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Only one input will be visible in the page.

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onchange="updatetest()" enabledisable="disabled" maxlength="32">
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onchange="updatetest()" enabledisable="disabled" maxlength="32">

function updatetest () {
$("#test").prop( enabledisable, false );
}
```

Comment: Does that syntax create an input field? What language is it?

Comment: Do you have a variable `enabledisable`? Do you have an element with the id `test`?

Comment: `enabledisable`? The HTML attribute is called [`disabled`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute).

Comment: @Digital Chris Yes the name and id will be test. What I am trying to do here is pass enabledisable to prop as parameter. I have defined enabledisable = "enable" or "disable" on each input fields.so the enable or disable should be passed to prop depending on the field. Is this possible? Like it should be $("#test").prop(disable, false);

Comment: How does that syntax set the ID? You can't have two elements with the same ID. Can you show the outputted HTML please?

Comment: @Popnoodles <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onchange="updatetest()" enabledisable="disabled" maxlength="32">

Comment: What I am trying to do is pass that enabledisable value to the prop as a parameter.

Comment: But it's not a valid parameter. When is it used? It can be done though.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Disable:

```
$('input[name="test"]').attr('disabled', true)
```

Enable:

```
$('input[name="test"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```