# html - Attributes with boolean values

Tags: html

What is the difference between:

`<input type="text" disabled>`

`<input type="text" disabled="true">`

`<input type="text" disabled=true>`

`<input type="text" disabled="1">`

`<input type="text" disabled=1>`

They all produce the same result, which is a disabled text input. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/R2jf2/).

But which of them is the most *(generally)* **correct** / **best** one to use?

Comment: [this link might also be usefull to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Comment: I'm happy with XHTML. I like it. I close things I open. I don't like HTML. I'm now always getting yelled at for leaving everything open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only the first one is valid. If you want to be compatible with XHTML, it should be `disabled="disabled"`:

> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., `selected="selected"`).
>
> In HTML, boolean attributes may appear in minimized form -- the attribute's value appears alone in the element's start tag. Thus, selected may be set by writing:
>
> ```
> <OPTION selected>
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> <OPTION selected="selected">
> ```
>
> Authors should be aware that many user agents only recognize the minimized form of boolean attributes and not the full form.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2

---

[In **HTML5**, the value can also be an empty string](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html):

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is a case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

it is considered to be [equivalent to the form with any value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty).

Comment: The part “many user agents only recognize the minimized form” in the HTML 4.01 spec hasn’t been true for many years.