# Not working call jquery methods after receiving the ajax response

Tags: jquery, response

When performing the ajax request produce some actions for the protection, namely:

```
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.calc").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}); // deactivate press CALCULATE
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}); // deactivate press CANCEL
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}) // deactivate press "X"
```

[image]

Buttons **CANCEL**, and **CALCULATE** and a cross "**X**" on the top - locked that is assigned to the attribute `disabled="disabled"` (this BootStrap).

After a response from the server I want to do the following:

```
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.calc").children().detach(); // remove button to Calculate
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").text("Close"); // change the name, click the CANCEL button to CLOSE
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").attr({"disabled":""}); // activate again the CLOSE button
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}) // activate again click the cross
```

[image]

As we see, only triggered function `.text("Close")` and everything else fails:

Here is the procedure actions send data and receive a response in the variable **data**, the procedure standard (keyguard happens when you click to CALCULATE the sample code did not lead because it works and probably make no sense to show it):

```
// CalculateDataCurrentMonth - Asynchronous request to the server
function CommitDataCurrentMonth()
{
var sendMonth = $(".label.label-default.current-month").text();
sendPost_CommitDataCurrentMonth(url, { sendMonth: sendMonth, fnCommitDataCurrentMonth: true });
}

// Prepare POST request
function sendPost_CommitDataCurrentMonth(url, obj)
{
$.post(url,obj,onAjaxSuccess_CommitDataCurrentMonth);
}

// Display server response
function onAjaxSuccess_CommitDataCurrentMonth(data)
{
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-body > div.input-group.date").html(data);
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.calc").children().detach();
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").attr({"disabled":""});
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").text("Close");
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").attr({"disabled":""});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `disabled` attribute instead of giving its ""/any other value. Button will remain disabled even if you provide blank value to it. Browser just checks for the presence of `disabled` attribute. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4ZY/) to demonstrate the correct value for `disabled` attribute.

You can use jQuery [**removeAttr**](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method

```
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").removeAttr("disabled"); 
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").removeAttr("disabled")
```

This might help [Correct value for disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)