# How to make an HTML dropdown option not clickable

Tags: html

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<select name="input"> 
<option value="Athletics:">Athletics:</option>
<option value="Running">Running</option>
<option value="Paragliding">Paragliding</option>
<option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
</select> 
<input type="Submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

I'm trying to make "Athletics:" NOT click-able, so users have to choose their specific sport. Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: remove it if you don't want to select that option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you plan on adding more options to this dropdown that aren't "Athlectics", I think what you may be looking for here is actually `<optgroup>`:

```
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup label="Athlectics">
   <option value="Running">Running</option>
   <option value="Paragliding">Paragliding</option>
   <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[It looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/UB7h9/):

[image]

This is useful for categorizing groups of options in a dropdown. "Athlectics" will not be a selectable option.

Otherwise I think you should just use "Athlectics" as the label for this field and remove it from the options:

```
<label>Athlectics: <select>...</select></label>
```

You should *always* use a label anyways for accessibility purposes, and it generally improves your UI.

If you really just want to disable an option, use the `disabled` attribute:

```
<option value="Athletics:" disabled>Athletics:</option>
```

Reference:

- `<optgroup>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup
- `<label>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label
- `disabled` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html
  Also: [Correct value for disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Comment: `<option value=""></option>` shows empty select, it's not a good idea for most users, it looks like broken form

Comment: @vladkras What is the preferred way to show a dropdown without a default value? Without the empty option, "Running" would already be selected when the page loads.

Comment: I think the goal was simply to show user that very this dropdown is for selecting kind of athletics, not for categorizing, grouping, etc. Showing empty dropdown is opposite.

Comment: The empty option is not essential to the answer, I just always use one because I believe it's best to have the user explicitly fill in a field rather than accidentally submit a default value.

Comment: @vladkras I think if the OP wants to add more groups or non-Athlectics options, then `optgroup` is the way, but if this will definitely be the only group then having "Athletics" as the `<label>` for this field is better.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to show "Athletics" rather than blank, but since it's not a selectable option I wonder if that's possible with solely html.

Answer (score 3):

add disabled="disabled" attribute to this option

```
<option value="Athletics:" disabled="disabled">Athletics:</option>
```

in some browsers it will be still on the 1st place, but 2nd option will be selected already, so you have to use javascript to make this word visible or just put in the label:

```
<label>Athletics:<select> ...[all other options]... </select></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this which would not allow users to select "Alhletics"

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<select name="input"> 
<option value="Athletics:" disabled>Athletics:</option>
<option value="Running">Running</option>
<option value="Paragliding">Paragliding</option>
<option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
</select> 
<input type="Submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

Or you could do this and add a label

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<label for="input">Athletics</label>
<select name="input"> 
<option value="Running">Running</option>
<option value="Paragliding">Paragliding</option>
<option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
</select> 
<input type="Submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution work for me is:

```
<select name="input" onmousedown="function(){return false;}"> 
<option value="Athletics:">Athletics:</option>
<option value="Running">Running</option>
<option value="Paragliding">Paragliding</option>
<option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
</select>
```