# c# webdriver - how can I verify 'disabled' attribute exists for a button

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to verify that a button loacted within my test page has a 'disabled' attribute applied to it.  Here is the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-1" data-type="plus" data-field="quantity" disabled="disabled">
```

How would I go about getting a handle on the 'disabled' attribute?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using c# but i think you can use getAttribute() method from Webdriver Api.

[c# getAttribute](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm)

So it should be something like that:

```
IWebElement button = locator to button;
button.getAttribute("disabled");
```

And then you can assert this value etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Remember "disabled" can have multiple values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute so it's up to you to ensure you cater for them.