# HtmlHelper extension method to disable controls and allow for multiple html attributes to be specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to write an extension method that will allow me to disable a control based on a security setting.  The code below works and accomplishes what I want. However - because it creates an object that represents **all** html attributes - I cannot specifiy additional attributes other than the disabled attribute that this code generates.

```
public static class SecurityHtmlHelper
{
    public static object EnableForPermission(this HtmlHelper html, Permission permission)
    {
        if (Security.HasPermission(permission))
            return new object();
        else
            return new { disabled = "disabled" };
    }
}
```

Example of how the above is used:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("permission test", "/", null, @Html.EnableForPermission(Permission.PM_PROCEDURE_ALT_SCEN_READ))
```

Desired usage example (does not build):

```
  @Html.ActionLink("permission test", "/", null, new { @style ="xyz", @Html.EnableForPermission(Permission.PM_PROCEDURE_ALT_SCEN_READ)})
```

No I dont want to use javascript and yes I realize disabling a link does not prevent the user from navigating to a page there are other controls in place for that.

Thx.

For reference on disabled attribute:
[Correct value for disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Comment: `disabled` is not a valid attribute for an `<a>` tag! What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: indeed it is not (although it works :)).  I will use the extension method on various controls, I badly chose <a> as an example.

Comment: It would not work on a `<a>` tag (except to generate invalid html). In the case in your question just do `@if (Security.HasPermission(Permission.PM_PROCEDURE_ALT_SCEN_READ)) { @Html.ActionLink(...) }` but you could create a html helper that that either returns an action link or null.

Comment: I am hoping for something more elegant (read shorter) than that.  There are hundreds of controls I need to use this on.  Also, I almost always want to render the control, but in a disabled state if permissions dont allow. thx.

Comment: Then you would need to create custom html helpers for each control (and potentially for each overload). In any case it would be simpler if you had a view model or `ViewBag` property (say `bool HasPermission`) to simplify the `if` blocks. And I assume you understand that disabled controls do not post back so their properties will be `null` and if they have any validation attributes, `ModelState` will be invalid.

Comment: Your points are well made, unfortunately I have to render the controls as disabled per client requirement.  Just hoping for a cleaner shorter syntax than big if blocks.

Comment: You can always create a helper that merges html attributes and adds the `disabled` attribute based on the permission something liks `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Html.EnablePermissionsFor(Permission.PM_PROCEDURE_ALT_SCEN_READ, new { @class = "myClass" }))`. Can give you an example if you want.

Comment: Yes please provide an example. Your comment appears to be what I am trying to do. If it dosnt work on <a> tags thats just the way it is. Most of what I need to use it on is inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `disabled` attribute wont work on an `<a>` tag (and its invalid html), but from your comments, you want to use the helper to apply it to controls anyway.

I'm not sure what `Security.HasPermission(permission)` does, but if its calling a service, then it does not belong in a helper. In any case I suggest you pass a `boolean` value to the view indicating if the permission applies, using a view model or `ViewBag` property, for example in the controller

```
ViewBag.HasPermission = Security.HasPermission(Permission.PM_PROCEDURE_ALT_SCEN_READ);
```

The helper needs to merge the html attributes you pass to it with the `disabled` attribute if applicable

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> EnableForPermission(object htmlAttributes, bool hasPermission)
{
  IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
  if (!hasPermission)
  {
    attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  return attributes;
}
```

and then in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.someProperty, EnableForPermission(new { @class = "someClass" }, ViewBag.HasPermission))
```