# How can I disabled select option(s) base on the JSON data got from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a dropdown-menu with a couple options. I want to loop through them and prop the `disabled` attribute on some of them base its result from the Ajax call.

[image]

This what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

---

**Sample Reportable Data**

```
s-00591 | true
s-00592 | false
s-00593 | false
s-00594 | false
s-00595 | false
```

---

**HTML**

```
<select class="rn-dropdown" id="rn-dd">
    <option value="class-view">class view</option>
    <!-- Students Populate Here  -->
    <option value="s-00591">Student S00591</option>
    <option value="s-00592">Student S00592</option>
    <option value="s-00593">Student S00593</option>
    <option value="s-00594">Student S00594</option>
    <option value="s-00595">Student S00595</option>
</select>
```

---

**JS**

```
success: function(reportable) {



    $.each(reportable , function(i, v) {

        var userId = v.userId;
        var reportable = v.reportable;
        var currentVal = userId;

        console.log('start');
        console.log(userId + " | " +reportable);
        $('#rn-dd option[value="' + currentVal + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
        console.log('end');

    });



}
```

---

Result,

I got no error displaying the console. 
But I keep seeing my dropdown-menu is not disabled as I want them to.

[image]

Any hints / helps / suggestions will mean a lot to me.

Comment: try `.prop('disabled', 'disabled')` refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @ChaitanyaGadkari.

Comment: Simple check `console.log($('#rn-dd option[value="' + currentVal + '"]').length)` to see if selector is matching

Comment: a boolean works just fine with `prop('disabled', boolean)` but it needs to be the boolean from the data

Comment: Provde real sample data so your code can be tested

Comment: @charlietfl : I got `0` when running your simple check suggestion.

Comment: My dropdown-menu is auto populate base on AJAX as well. Is it because of my `prop disabled` is loading before the dropdown-menu is even populate. If so, how can I make sure make that they run in the properly order ?

Comment: Well that ajax makes a huge difference and should have been mentioned in the beginning. Need to show how both ajax are integrated into the code and when they get triggered

Comment: @charlietfl : I got it to work now by loading it in the proper order. :) I really appreciated your concern and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.prop('disabled', true);` I believe its a typo or something, as it disable every options.
2. The `true`, `false` value in your jsonObj may be `String`. So, no matter the value is `'true'` or `'false'`, its treaded as `true`, so `!reportable` is always false, which means it won't disable any option.

You may have to check if its a string first, like :

```
reportable = (typeof v.reportable === 'string') ? v.reportable === 'true' : v.reportable
```

To convert it to Boolean first.

```js
var reportable = [
  {userId: 's-00591', reportable: 'true'},
  {userId: 's-00592', reportable: 'false'},
  {userId: 's-00593', reportable: 'false'},
  {userId: 's-00594', reportable: 'false'},
  {userId: 's-00595', reportable: 'false'}
];

// Check the diff between string and boolean.
var reportable2 = [
  {userId: 's-00591', reportable:  true},
  {userId: 's-00592', reportable: false},
  {userId: 's-00593', reportable: false},
  {userId: 's-00594', reportable: false},
  {userId: 's-00595', reportable: false}
];



$.each(reportable , function(i, v) {
  var userId = v.userId;
  var reportable = v.reportable;
  var currentVal = userId;

  console.log('start');
  console.log(userId + " | " +reportable);
  $('#rn-dd option[value="' + currentVal + '"]').prop('disabled', !reportable);
  console.log('end');

});

$.each(reportable2 , function(i, v) {
  var userId = v.userId;
  var reportable = v.reportable;
  var currentVal = userId;

  console.log('start');
  console.log(userId + " | " +reportable);
  $('#rn-dd2 option[value="' + currentVal + '"]').prop('disabled', !reportable);
  console.log('end');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rn-dropdown" id="rn-dd">
    <option value="class-view">class view</option>
    <!-- Students Populate Here  -->
    <option value="s-00591">Student S00591</option>
    <option value="s-00592">Student S00592</option>
    <option value="s-00593">Student S00593</option>
    <option value="s-00594">Student S00594</option>
    <option value="s-00595">Student S00595</option>
</select>

<select class="rn-dropdown" id="rn-dd2">
    <option value="class-view">class view</option>
    <!-- Students Populate Here  -->
    <option value="s-00591">Student S00591</option>
    <option value="s-00592">Student S00592</option>
    <option value="s-00593">Student S00593</option>
    <option value="s-00594">Student S00594</option>
    <option value="s-00595">Student S00595</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I really appreciated the snippet, and the precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think you should check value of `currentVal` in your code , is it giving value like `s-00591`  or not , becaues if you get wrong value there it doesnt disable option you want.

and try out `.prop('disabled','disabled')`

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing you're trying should work if you pass the needed value instead of true to `prop('disabled', true)`, you just don't use what you know.

Here's a basic example, discarding AJAX and other things unrelated to the core of your question:

Code:

```js
var users = [
  {userId: 's-00591', reportable: true},
  {userId: 's-00592', reportable: false},
  {userId: 's-00593', reportable: false},
  {userId: 's-00594', reportable: false},
  {userId: 's-00595', reportable: false},
];

$.each(users , function(index, user) {
  $('#rn-dd option[value="' + user.userId + '"]').prop('disabled', !user.reportable);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<select class="rn-dropdown" id="rn-dd">
    <option value="class-view">class view</option>
    <!-- Students Populate Here  -->
    <option value="s-00591">Student S00591</option>
    <option value="s-00592">Student S00592</option>
    <option value="s-00593">Student S00593</option>
    <option value="s-00594">Student S00594</option>
    <option value="s-00595">Student S00595</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem in code might be cause because of wrong value of variable userId which is used as part of selector

Comment: You're right, revised my example code to reflect a more accurate representation of the question's data structure. Thanks.