# Conditionally set the disabled state of a bootstrap button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following button in my view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary button</button>
```

I want to add the `disabled` property to it if and only a certain condition is `true`. How do I this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should do this two or more way:

```
<button type="button" class="your-class btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    if(Condition){
      $('.your-class').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
</script>

OR
In The rails term 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary <%= conditon ? "disabled" : ""%>">Primary button</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use the rails helper `button_tag` with a boolean check

```
<%= button_tag "Primary button", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 
  disabled: condition_check_method %>
```

Answer (score 2):

@[Ropeney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38196834/1763929)'s way is the RoR way, but here's another solution:

```
<% #some condition %>
<% foo == bar ? ( disabled = "disabled") : (disabled = "") %>

<!-- insert "disabled" or "" (empty string) in the markup -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" <%= disabled %> >Primary button</button>
```

Note: we can use only `disabled` in HTML5 - [Correct value for disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled="<%= @check_condition ? 'disabled' : '' %>">Primary button</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" <%= @check_condition ? 'disabled' : '' %>">Primary button</button>
```