# Disable button depending on select option using jquery?

Tags: jquery

On selecting *option 1* the button must be disabled, enable the button when remaining options are selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("option[value='1']")){
     $("button").prop('disabled',true);
    }
  else{
    $("button").prop('disabled',false);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: It's easy. It must be disabled when there is an attribute `disabled` whatever it has value.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai rolled back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$("option[value='1']")` would return a jQuery object which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) always so that if statement doesn't make any sense. Although your code only runs once when the page is loaded.

You need to bind a  [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to update the button based on the current value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // bind change event handler
  $('#opt').change(function() {
    // update disabled property
    $("button").prop('disabled', this.value == 1);
    // trigger change event to set initial value
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#opt').change(function() {
    $("button").prop('disabled', $(this).val() == 1);//will disable if current value is equals to 1

  }).change()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button>button</button>
```

On change event check value of select then depending on value set the disable of button

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remove attribute `disabled` when you want to show things. Read [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute) and see the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").prop('disabled',true);
  $('#opt').change(function(){
     if($(this).val()==1){
       $("button").attr('disabled','disabled');
      }
    else{
      $("button").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#opt").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
                $("button").prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $("button").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button disabled >button</button>
```