# Why is the "true" boolean value the "wrong attribute value"?

Tags: html

I have the following button:

```
<button id="=" style=width:150px;height:150px;font-size:100px; onclick="equalFunction()" disabled="true">=</button>
```

however in the `disabled="true"` my IDE recognizes the `"true"` value to be the "wrong attribut value" does anyone know how to solve this? The code still works, its just annoying to see it be highlighted.

Comment: It should be `disabled="disabled"` or `disabled`

Comment: HTML working and HTML being correct are, unfortunately, fairly different things. Browsers will pretty much try to render anything you throw at them, regardless of strict correctness.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/what-is-the-correct-value-for-the-disabled-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html):

> A number of attributes in HTML5 are boolean attributes. The presence
>   of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and
>   the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is a case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So with a boolean attribute like `disabled`, it's presence alone is enough and it needs  no value, although virtually every web browser will still accept it. Therefore, you should use either `disabled` (alone) or `disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set it to true. Do something like this:

```
<button id="=" style=width:150px;height:150px;font-size:100px; onclick="equalFunction()" disabled>=</button>
```