# Display the correct value in dropdown retrieved from mysql table

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown list which should be displaying the correct value of the record retrieved from mysql table. Below is what I have tried so far:

```
   <strong>Authority Id: *</stong><select name="authid">
   <?php

            $authid = $row['AuthorityId'];
    $selectedId = array(
    5, 6, 7);
    $selection = array(
            5 => "Admin",
            6 => "Employee",
            7 => "Student" );
    foreach($selection as $value){
        $text = $value;
        echo '<option value="'.$selectedId.'" selected="'.$authid.'">'.$text.'</option>';
    }
  ?>
  </select>
```

But it's not displaying the correct value. Can someone help me figure out what went wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: what is the output? what is the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<strong>Authority Id: *</strong><select name="authid">
<?php

$authid = $row['AuthorityId']; // Get $authid from database
$selection = array( // Create Index Of AuthIDs and AuthNames
    5 => "Admin",
    6 => "Employee",
    7 => "Student" );

foreach($selection as $key => $value) // Loop Through $selection, Where $key is AuthID and $value is AuthName
{
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '"'; // Start Menu Item
    if ($authid == $key) // Check If AuthID from $selection equals $authid from database
        echo ' selected="selected"'; // Select The Menu Item If They Match
    echo '>' . $value . '</option>'; // End Menu Item
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, I tried to explain how it all works the best I can, if you need anymore elaboration ask. =o)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14111114/66482) provided by criptic is better - the presence of the selected attribute seems to be enough to select an option in some browsers - see [the answers to this question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/what-values-can-appear-in-the-selected-attribute-of-the-option-tag).

---

You're using the `selected` attribute of the option tag incorrectly:

```
<strong>Authority Id: *</stong><select name="authid">
<?php
 $authid = $row['AuthorityId'];

 $selectedId = array(5, 6, 7);
 $selection = array(
        5 => "Admin",
        6 => "Employee",
        7 => "Student" );

 foreach($selection as $value){
    $text = $value;
    $selected = '';
    if ($selectedID == $authid) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$selectedId.'" selected="'.$selected.'">'.$text.'</option>';
 }
?>
</select>
```