# Setting selected atrribute onClick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript skills are not the best, but I've been working on them lately and one thing I wanted to do was set attributes for html option tags. I posted the project on jfiddle to make it a little easier to see. You can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YZ42J/2/). I think I'm just one line of code off or something.

How would I remove the selected attribute from option 2 and create the selected attribute for option 1? In other words so that when I open 'another-popup', option 1 is selected instead of option 2.

I recommend you check out the jsFiddle link, but I posted the code on this question as well.
The javascript for the update link:

```
function updateSelected(id, removeID, parentID) {
    document.getElementById(parentID).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("selected","selected");
    document.getElementById(removeID).removeAttribute("selected")
}
```

The html:

```
<a href="#box" rel="popup">Popup</a>

<div id="box" class="popup">
<a href="#another-box" rel="popup" onClick="updateSelected("1", "2", "box");">Another box</a>
</div>
<div id="another-box" class="popup">
<form>
    <select>
        <option id="1">option 1</option>
        <option id="2" selected>option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't have numeric IDs even though some browsers support it and use single quotes inside double quotes. See console

Comment: i have to, because i generate them dynamically with a php loop

Comment: @mplungjan strictly speaking, numeric IDs are an HTML5 feature.

Comment: @Alex no you don't have to, just put a prefix on them in your PHP.

Comment: oh okay, yeah i mean i do that, i didn't for simplicity sake here, but they all have the id="option-1" or something like that

Comment: @Alex: I updated your JS Fiddle link to point to a version without the minified section of code for readability purposes (the problem might not be *in* that section of the code, but it helps to be able to easily read what's going on in a script).

Comment: @Alnitak As I said: "even though some browsers support is" - it is an abomination and will fail on all non-html5 browsers and not fail on html5 browsers if not numeric

Comment: @mplungjan sure, browser support is not (yet) universal.  But it's hardly an "abomination" - it's a W3C standard feature!

Comment: Anything that will fail and which will be misunderstood and abused by mistake is an abomination in my eyes. Since early '90s they forced us to use IDs beginning with letters or select characters and now they for some reason allow numeric IDs which people will fall over time and time again

Comment: IMHO your argument only holds true if they had made the change the other way around.  _Relaxing_ rules very rarely breaks things, so long as people don't assume those changes are retrospective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change which entry is selected you should change the `.selected` *property*, and not the *attribute*.

```
document.getElementById(id).selected = true;
```

The attribute just sets the *initial* value of the control, whereas the *property* sets the current value.

Note that there's also no need to *remove* the property from the previously selected element.  That happens automatically since (by default) only one element may be "selected" at once.

Alternatively, set the `.value` property on the enclosing `<select>` to be the same as the value of the desired `<option>` element.  The value will be that of the `value` attribute on the `<option>` element, or the contained text if there is no `value` attribute.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/C98Wc/

Comment: okay, i've been trying to make it work but it still wont change it for me. I don't know why. Check out my updated link http://jsfiddle.net/YZ42J/7/

Comment: look in your JS console.  It doesn't work because `updateSelected` is wrapped (by jsfiddle) inside an `onLoad` handler and DOM0 handlers have to be global.  Change it to `wrap (head)` instead and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/MYarB/

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById(id).selected=1;//or true
```

and the other way around is to

```
document.getElementById(id).selected=0;//or false
```

@Alnitak - thanks for the correction.

Comment: `.selected` is a boolean property.

Comment: @Alnitak from what i have understood this is correct; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/what-values-can-appear-in-the-selected-attribute-of-the-option-tag

Comment: no, you've missed the point.  As an _attribute_ you pass a string, but as a _property_ (which is what you have with `.selected`) you pass a _boolean_.

Answer (score 0):

Watch your quotes, try replacing `<a>` tag with this:

```
<a href="#another-box" rel="popup" onClick="updateSelected('1', '2', 'box');">Another box</a>
```

You can't use double quotes within double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery all the way? Also use single quotes inside your double quotes

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SyJnt/)

```
<a href="#another-box" rel="popup" id="another" >Another box</a>


$(function() {
    $('a[rel*=popup]').leanModal({ top : 200, closeButton: ".popup-close" });       
    $("#another").on("click",function(e) {
        updateSelected("o1","box");
        return false; // cancel click - can be e.preventDefault() instead 
    });


});         
function updateSelected(id, parentID) {
    $("#"+parentID).css("display","none"); // or .hide()
    $("#"+id).prop("selected",true);
}
```

Comment: there's no need to remove the property from the original entry.  Unless it's a "multiselect" they're all mutually exclusive.

Comment: it's still wrong.  `.prop('selected')` requires a _boolean_, not a _string_, and there's no need for a `return false` in a function that isn't an event handler.