# Maintain select values from dynamic drop down list after refresh

Tags: php, html, netbeans, selected

I have a form consisting of 11 elements (*input* and *select* tags). The form has form validation that prompts an error message next to field when a user inputs incorrect data.  I want to maintain the correct data entered into the fields after the page is refreshed.

For instance, let's say that 10 fields where populated correctly and 1 field incorrectly.  When the user presses the submit button, an error message is shown near the field. What I want to do is to keep the 10 correct values selected so the user does no have to start all over again.

For the input elements, this is working fine but for the select elements this is not working.  **Important is that I am populating the drop down list dynamically with PHP.**

Is this possible to do in PHP since I cannot figure out how?

Below is an example of how I am generating a drop down list of a select element.

```
    select name="location">
  <?php
     include("../includes/db_connect.php"); 
     $sql_loc = "SELECT description FROM location ORDER BY description ASC";
     $result_loc = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_loc);

     if(mysqli_num_rows($result_loc) > 0){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_loc)){
       echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) . '">' 
       . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) 
       . '</option>';
     }
    }                                             

      ?> 
    </select>
```

As for the input elements I am achieving this using the below:

```
<input type="text" name="serial" value="<?php echo $serial;?>">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: @Blackbam Just for future reference, the link that you posted has a very different question

Comment: @asish Yes but a duplicate is not about questions but about answers. The Thread I linked contains an answer that you have to put the selected HTML attribute and this solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="location">
    <?php
        include("../includes/db_connect.php"); 
        $sql_loc = "SELECT description FROM location ORDER BY description ASC";
        $result_loc = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_loc);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result_loc) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_loc)){
                $selected = "";
                if ($row['description'] == $location) {
                    $selected = " selected";
                }
                echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) . '"' . $selected . '>' 
                . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) 
                . '</option>';
            }
        }                                             
    ?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible to do in PHP since I cannot figure out how?

Yes it is possible to keep the values selected, by using the [**selected**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) attribute on the option elements.

For instance, the `<option>` tag below contains that attribute:

```
<option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
```

If you care about XHTML validation, use `selected="selected"` - refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588336/1575353) for more information.

```
<option value="value2" selected="selected">Value 2</option>
```

From the [examples section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples) of the MDN documentation for [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), the following HTML is listed:

```html
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="select"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'name'-->
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

#### Rendering a select list with PHP

To achieve this with the PHP code, the **selected** attribute needs to be conditionally added to the option.

First, before the *while* loop, store the selected location in a variable:

```
$selectedLocation = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
    //Get selected value from values submitted with form
    //use $_GET if form is submitted via GET
    $selectedLocation = $_POST['location']; 
}
```

Then in the *while* loop, set that *selected* attribute when the matching option is found (i.e. when `$selectedLocation == $row['description']`).

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
    $selected = ''; //default to empty string - not selected
    if ($selectedLocation == $row['description']) {
        $selected = 'selected';   
    }
    echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) . '" '.$selected.'>' 
   . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) 
   . '</option>';
 }
```

See a demosntration of this in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cvfj-kues).

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in the [as duplicate linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518002/367456) the `selected` attribute is to mark the option that has been submitted. The `selected` attribute addresses the issue to make the selected value visible.

Additionally your code can benefit from data-binding the select element to the (SQL) data in a modular way.

Let us not care for a moment on the retrieval of the data and just say they come from a **Generator**:

```
/**
 * @param string $name of the select field
 * @param string $value of the select field
 * @param Generator $data to use as select field option values
 * @return string HTML of the select element
 */
function select($name, $value, Generator $data) {
    $buffer = sprintf('<select name="%s">', htmlspecialchars($name));
    foreach ($data as $option) {
        $buffer .= sprintf(
            '<option%s>%s</option>',
            $value === $option ? ' selected' : '',
            htmlspecialchars($option)
        );
    }
    $buffer .= "</select>\n";
    return $buffer;
}
```

This little function returns the HMTL of a select element with the data from a **Generator** selecting an existing value (if part of the options).

Combining it with any generator, for example from a data-source, it can be easily put into your forms template script:

```
<form method="post">

<?= select('location', $_POST['location'] ?? 'default value',
    datasource($connection, "SELECT description FROM location ORDER BY description ASC", "description")
) ?>

</form>
```

So if you've got 10 selects, this can be easily adopted. As the database connection as you know it is passed to the `datasource` function, it would be interesting to see what that function actually does. That function is even more simple:

```
/**
 * @param mysqli $mysqli
 * @param string $query
 * @param string $field from query result to use as option values
 * @return Generator
 */
function datasource(mysqli $mysqli, $query, $field) {
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($result) foreach ($result as $row) {
        yield $row[$field];
    }
}
```

It queries the query on the database connection (it's a different way of writing as in your code, but it's the same `$connection` as in your example) and then iterates over the result (if there is a result). Then *yielding* each option value. That `yield` is a special form of returning from a function creating a **Generator** which is used in the `select` function for output, by having the **Generator** in the `foreach` loop there. Each yielding becomes one iteration of the **Generator**.

I hope this shows how you can benefit from dividing your code into functions. Values that change should be put into variables. This is easily done by creating functions and using parameters for these values. You sort of extend the language to your own special needs, like creating select elements.

Answer (score 0):

Edit and try:

```
<select name="location">
<?php
    include("../includes/db_connect.php"); 
    $sql_loc = "SELECT description FROM location ORDER BY description ASC";
    $result_loc = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_loc);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_loc) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_loc)){
            $selected = "";
            if ($row['description'] == $location) {
                $selected = " selected";
            }
            echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) . '"' . $selected . '>' 
            . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) 
            . '</option>';
        }
    }                                             
?>
```