# In a HTML select element, why the last option that has selected=false is selected?

Tags: html, select, selected

I have a `select` element with `option` elements in it. Some of the options have attribute `selected` set to false, and some don't have it set at all.

```html
<select>
  <option selected=false>1</option>
  <option selected=false>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option selected=false>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
```

It seems that when no elements have `selected` set to `true`, the last element with `selected` set to `false` is the one selected by default when the element is created.

This behavior is not intuitive, and in this case I would expected the first `option` with undefined `selected` to be selected, and definitely not one that is explicitly unselected.

What causes this behavior? Is it defined anywhere?

Comment: It's invalid. You use `selected="selected"` or you don't use it at all. Basically, what's happening is that HTML sees that you have the property selected, and will select it. Check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/what-values-can-appear-in-the-selected-attribute-of-the-option-tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `disabled` is a boolean attribute. When it is present, it is on, and it doesn't matter what value it has, so the last element that has the `selected` attribute gets selected. Even though you write `false`, it is still interpreted as `true` (see [What values can appear in the "selected" attribute of the "option" tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/what-values-can-appear-in-the-selected-attribute-of-the-option-tag)).

Answer (score -1):

Why are using selected False can you please explain the purpose.
Try it.

```
<select>
  <option disabled>1</option>
  <option disabled>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option disabled>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `disabled` is a different thing than absence of `selected`.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to selected="false".